# Align figure without text wrapping

Tags: context

I would like to left align a figure on a page and not have text wrapping. This MWE centres the figure which is not what I want:

```
\starttext

\placefigure
[nonumber,here]
{}
{\externalfigure[cow]}

\input knuth


\stoptext
```

If I change the `here` to `left` the text wraps around the figure.

Comment: @Skillmon: I am not sure what you mean as the code above compiles and shows the figure centered whereas I want the figure aligned to the left margin and the text to stay in the same position.

Comment: It would help if you put the question in context ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
\starttext
\externalfigure[cow]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

\placefigure creates a floating object.

See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics

Comment: But what if I say `\setupalign[middle]` and still want the figure flush left?

Comment: I just tried it and the image is still flush left. I can't tell you why, but that's the way it comes out.

Comment: In this case it is because you are still in vertical mode, but try for instance `\dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow]`.  Anyways, I find your solution suboptimal as there is no easy way to add a caption if needed later.

Answer (score 6):

Gernot’s answer is correct, however, I have some improvements to suggest.  First of all, `\setupfloats[location=left]` will align *all* floats to the left, i.e. also tables and whichever other floats you have.  Second, I strongly advise to use the `\start...\stop` variants of everything, including `placefigure` as most of them will insert the correct code into the PDF and thus allows you to create [Tagged PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Logical_structure_and_accessibility).

```
\startsetups floats:left
  \setupfloat[location=left]
\stopsetups

\definestartstop
  [leftfloats]
  [setups=floats:left]

\starttext

\startleftfloats
  \startplacefigure
    [
      location={none,here},
    ]
    \externalfigure[cow][width=.3\textwidth]
  \stopplacefigure
\stopleftfloats

\input ward

\startplacefigure
  [
    location={none,here},
  ]
  \externalfigure[cow][width=.3\textwidth]
\stopplacefigure

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Henri. Thank you. Does '\setupfloat' only affect the next figure

Comment: @pdoak No, it affects all of them.

Comment: what if I want all floats to be centered apart from one which I want on the left without text wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell context to position floats flush left using

```
\setupfloats[location=left]
```

[image]

```
\setupfloats[location=left]
\starttext
\placefigure[nonumber,here]{}{\externalfigure[cow]}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```